# move information on a combox on userform to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a userform that is pulling information from a spreadsheet, for user to pick, I then need to write their selection to the spreadsheet (In a different sheet where the correct answer is held, I have the code to work out how many correct answers are inputted.

so spreadsheet will look like this

sheet one will hold all questions and is unimportant here

sheet two picks 10 random questions from sheet one, and is held like so

question id   topic    question    answer 1 answer 2 answer 3 answer 4 correct selected
1               a         sss        2       3          4        5         ""

sheet 3 is what i use to create the combo box

I need to have it so that what is selected in the combo box is then written in the relevant row in sheet 2

please help

Answer (score 0):

Okay; first you need to provide us with what you have tried so far and where the problem is, for us to be able to help, since in your question you are saying that you are using a "userform" but then you go on to say that it is actually a combobox you have created on Sheet3.

Assuming it is a combobox you have created on "Sheet3":

[AddCombobox http://im51.gulfup.com/1fszrk.png](http://im51.gulfup.com/1fszrk.png)

[Sheet3 http://im51.gulfup.com/HwEYy4.png](http://im51.gulfup.com/HwEYy4.png)

You have to populate your first combobox "Combobox1" to include all the question ids upon running of the sheet, as this is what we will use to identify in which row the data will have to be written. Make sure that your questionid field has only unique values!

So add the below into "ThisWorkbook" code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Sheet3").ComboBox1.Clear

Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow
Worksheets("Sheet3").ComboBox1.AddItem Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

This should load all the question ids into Combobox1. Now add the below in to the "Sheet3" code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set oLookin = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & Lastrow)
sLookFor = Worksheets("Sheet3").ComboBox1.Value
Set oFound = oLookin.Find(What:=sLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & oFound.Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").ComboBox2.Value 'change "B" to any other column
End If
End Sub
```

This should find the row of the questionid selected in "Combobox1" and then write the value of Combobox2 as it changes to the selected column of the corresponding row.

Sample workbook: https://www.mediafire.com/?08133ox6kty4gv3

The answer could have been better with a more detailed question.